# tkinter: switching between frames doesnt work correctly

Tags: tkinter

so i wrote the code for switching between 2 frames, I tried the destroy() method and i got no errors but when i click the button, the frame does not destroy correctly

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font  as tkfont

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()



class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self = tk.Frame(master,width=1200,height=700)
        self.pack()

        self.create_button = tk.Button(self,text='CREATE +',command=lambda: master.switch_frame(Create_list),width=15,height=2)                  # =lambda: master.switch_frame(Create_list)
        self.create_button.place(x=100,y=300)

class Create_list(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self = tk.Frame(master,width=1200,height=700)
        self.pack()

        tk.Label(self, text="Page one", font=('Helvetica', 18, "bold")).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Button(self, text="Go back to start page",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(StartPage)).pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

this is the result, as you can see when i click create button it does not destroy but spawn the new frame right bellow it:

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGdj4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are redefining `self` to be a frame that is in `master` rather than in the page itself. You should never redefine `self` this way. What happens is that you destroy the page, but all of the widgets are in the second frame. That second frame is in master so it doesn't get destroyed when you destroy the page.

If you truly want to treat your "page" as an object, every widget you create in a "page" needs to be a child of `self` or one of its descendants.

Unrelated to that problem, you are using `place`. `place` won't cause the containing frame to grow or shrink. Unless there is a *very* compelling reason to use `place`, you should use `pack` or `grid`. If you do use `place`, it is up to you to set a reasonable size for the containing widget.

The following example shows the proper way to create a page. Notice that it does *not* redefine `self`, but instead puts everything directly in the real *self*. Also, it uses `pack` rather than `place`.

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.create_button = tk.Button(self,text='CREATE +',
            command=lambda: master.switch_frame(Create_list),
            width=15,height=2)
        self.create_button.pack(side="top")
```

Also, you should probably use appropriate options when packing the frame so that it fills the window:

```
self._frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: Thanks,it worked, the reason i use place() because I size the window to 1200x700 and place the buttons and text, where can i add the geometry() in this current code?  or is there any other way to do the same?